# Trouble with Adobe Creative Cloud

Tags: adobe

I am having issues with Adobe Creative Cloud.  This started about 3 months ago.  I get a timed out message whenever I attempt to connect to CC. I have uninstalled CC and every attempt I have made at a new install gives me the same answer:  That the server has timed out and I need to check my internet connection or my firewall. Error code 207.  I have a hardwired internet connection and have checked my firewall settings (from what I can tell, I have added exclusion for adobe.com and creativecloud.com).

Can anyone help me here??? I have my computer specs listed below.

iMac (27-inch, Late 2013)
Processor: 3.4 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory:  16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Startup Disk: Macintosh HD
Graphics:  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 775M 2048 MB
OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5
(also, I have Bitedefender Antivirus for Mac.  I have turned OFF the Continuous Scan... just in case this was causing the problem.)

Comment: Do you have any evidence this isn't an Adobe server or a network problem ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't related to any Apple product.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of side suggestions:

1. You are paying for cloud service, so you should have paid support from Adobe if you can't solve this quickly. They should have an article explaining exactly what ports need to be open for your firewall.
2. You could disable the firewall for a short test to rule that in/out as cause of your issues.

If you want to go this alone, enable logging in the firewall and make a new user account. Open the CC Desktop app in the new user and attempt to sign in with your Adobe ID.

This will test system settings and the app. It will check your ID is active and get you firewall data if you are blocking a needed port. It will also separate the system from your main user settings so you can narrow the cause.